# word image im imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to create an image containing "word" as an image which is centrally assigned . I used the following command :

```
echo "word" | convert -font Helvetica -pointsize 32 label:@- cmd.png
```

but the resulting image I got does not centrally align the image and also I want to have my image automatically cropped with respect to word . I am not able to find any flag which can do so .

Comment: I have tried many flags , but not able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick will attempt to grow the image size to include all the characters read from [stdin](/questions/tagged/stdin). Use the [-trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) flag to reduce the image to the nearest pixel

```sh
echo "Words are nice" | convert -font Helvetica -pointsize 32 label:@- -trim -border 1 cmd.png
```

[image: Words are nice]

*border added for reference*